# Testing different scenarios using one browser instance in java, selenium, cucumber and JUnit runner

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

There is an application am working on where the process of logging in takes far too long, am looking for a way of executing all scenarios and multiple features with one chrome driver instance.
Here is my hooks code

```
    @Before(order = 0)
public void launchbrowser() {
    reader = new ConfigFileReader();
    pro = reader.ConfigFile();
    
    try {
        BaseClass.setUp();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@After
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
    File destPath;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss");
    Date curDate = new Date(); String strDate = sdf.format(curDate);
    File screenshot_with_scenario_name = (((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE));

    if(scenario.isFailed())
    {
        destPath=new File("./test-output/Screenshots/Failed/" + scenario.getName()+ strDate + ".png");
    }
    else{
        destPath=new File("./test-output/Screenshots/Passed/" + scenario.getName()+ strDate + ".png");
    }

    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot_with_scenario_name,destPath);
    } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BaseClass.Closebrowser();
}
```

And here is Baseclass where driver is setup

```
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maxwell Maragia you can try using global hooks @BeforeAll and @AfterAll. You can find the details here https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java